# "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect" preventing debugger from launching

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

I am trying to run a debugger, but it consistently sends back a message with the above quote and an option to open the launch.json file.

```
 {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what my launch.json file looks like. I've currently tried:

- Deleting and recreating the launch.json file
- Altering the launch.json file according to [Time out waiting for launcher to connect in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71920044/time-out-waiting-for-launcher-to-connect-in-vs-code)
- Going back to an earlier version of the python extension
- Uninstalling all of my python extensions and reinstalling them

My Python version is currently 3.9.0 according to the text at the bottom right corner of the VScode window. The rest of VScode with Python appears to work as expected.

This is what my terminal looks like:

```
PS C:\Users\alexs\Documents\BEng\Software 1\Formative Assessment\2\SOF1-2022-23-EvenYears-Formative-2\ClosedExamination> \Users\alexs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.7.exe' 'c:\Users\alexs\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '57863' '--' 'c:\Users\alexs\Documents\BEng\Software 1\Formative Assessment\2\SOF1-2022-23-EvenYears-Formative-2\ClosedExamination\test_question_4.py'
>>  'C:
```

Comment: Can you provide the content displayed in the terminal when you debug? There is no problem with your `launch.json`. Have you tried reopen Debug Console?

Comment: It may happen if the CPU is too busy. How "heavy" is your code and do you run other applications or software which may overburden the CPU and memory?